# Rewrite Aspx to PHP on Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

On my Nginx server I need to rewrite all aspx requests to php.

```
    location ~ \.aspx$ {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)\.aspx$ /$1.php;
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to load an aspx page the browser just downloads it.

Comment: It downloads `*.php` file contents or what? What is the exact problem?

Comment: it downloads the file .aspx with php code inside of it, hard to explain my situation but I need to load php within a aspx/asp.net file.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need to execute `php` code under `.asp(x)` file extension? Right?